# Help with understanding the solution to a volume of a solid $y = x, y = 0, x = 4, x = 7$ about $x = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

My assignment has this as its instructions:

$$y = x, y = 0, x = 4, x = 7$$
About the line $x=1$

The first thing I did was draw the line $y=x, y=0, x=4, x=7$

I then shaded the region bounded by these lines and drew the approximating washer.  The solution I worked out, however, didn't match the solution in the solutions manual.  So I have some specific questions about the answer in the solutions manual.

The solutions manual says the following:
For $0 \le y \lt 4$, a cross-section is an annulus with inner radius $4-1$ and outer radius $7-1$, the area of which is $A_{1}(y) = \pi(7-1)^2-\pi(4-1)^2$.  For $4 \le y \le 7$, a cross-section is an annulus with inner radius $y-1$ and outer radius $7-1$, the area of which is $A_{2}(y)=\pi(7-1)^2 - \pi(y-1)^2$.

Why is the inner radius $4-1$ and the outer radius $7-1$ when these don't seem to accurately describe the radius?  In other words, why are they using a $-1$?

After this point I understand how to setup the integral and solve it, but the method they used to get to this point is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you’re revolving the region about the line $x=1$, so the radius at any point of the region is the distance from that point to the line $x=1$. If the point is $\langle a,b\rangle$, the radius is $|a-1|$, the distance between $a$ and $1$. In your case the inner edge of the region (*inner* with respect to the axis of revolution) is on the line $x=4$; every point on that line is at distance $|4-1|=4-1=3$ from the axis of revolution at $x=1$. Similarly, the every point on the outer edge has $x$-coordinate $7$ and is therefore at a distance of $|7-1|=7-1=6$ from the axis of revolution.

Comment: This also makes perfect sense, so thank you!  Just to make sure I understand, so if my solid was being rotated around $x=6$ instead of $-1$ it would $-6$ away from origin?

Comment: @inquisitor: Careful: your solid is being revolved about $x=1$, not $x=-1$. You get a minus sign because you’re looking for the horizontal distance between $1$ and something else (in this case $4$ or $7$). If the axis of revolution were $x=6$, the problem would be much more complicated, because the axis would run through the region: everything in the region between $x=5$ and the axis would already be generated by the part of the region between the axis and $x=7$. Let’s not deal with that until you’ve got the easier ones down. If the axis were at $x=8$, putting it outside your region, ...

Comment: ... the edge of your region at $x=7$ would be closest to the axis, and you’d get an inner radius of $|7-8|=1$, the distance between $7$ and $8$. The edge at $x=4$ would be furthest from the axis, so you’d get an outer radius of $|4-8|=4$, the distance between $4$ and $8$.

Answer (score 1):

The axis of rotation is the line $x=1$. The radii we're talking about are measured as distances from the axis of rotation. That's why the $-1$'s are there.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you!